# Display image using Nodejs only

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I am trying to display an image by only using Node js. I have been searching for a way to do this, but the only examples that I can find involve HTML and ID's within the HTML which I do not want to use. Sorry I do not have any code to go along with my question, but is there a way to avoid all HTML and just use Node js or a specific node js module to store the image in a variable which would later be used to display the image?

Comment: Display the image, how? Node is a server-side application framework. Are you intending to serve the image as a URL? If so, you might check out Express, which gives options to serve an image from raw image data or static files.

Comment: @Thebluefish: Not *server*-side, just not browser-based. So servers, apps on a desktop, etc.

Comment: @Thebluefish I'd like to display the actual image itself, not as a URL...is that possible?

Comment: Node's only built-in UI is console/stream based. If you want to do more, you use some kind of UI package for it. Most of those that I'm aware of are based on web technologies (e.g., [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)), but if you search you may find a UI toolkit that works another way (perhaps plugging into X, or Windows, or GTK+, or...).

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Node does not have a GUI. You might look at Electron for that.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks guys for the input and advice

Answer (score 0):

> store the image in a variable which would later be used to display the image

You can achieve this by having NodeJS print you the [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) of the image. It will be a rather large block of string, so quite cumbersome, but certainly will let you fetch an image from NodeJS without using a web browser/HTML.

You can also launch an arbitrary image viewer of your choice by having NodeJS launch a [child process.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)